# What is the SLF4J equivalent to Log4j's "-Dlog4j.debug" option?

Tags: java, logging, glassfish, log4j, slf4j

I have a J2EE application running under GF2 and OS X 10.8.4 which has suddenly, and without an y apparent cause stopped logging all of the information my team expects it to.

When deployed under Windows or Linux this issue does not occur. We suspect that it is either an OS update or some issue with the logging subsystem.

The application uses SLF4j and I would like to know what it's doing and where it might be getting its properties from. Under log4j there is an option "-Dlog4j.debug"  which writes to STDOUT and tells where it is loading its properties from. Is there an equivalent option in SLF4J?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slf4j is just a facade - an common API - for any of several different logging backends.  How to do what you want, depends on which backend you use.  E.g. logback has the debug attribute in the configuration file telling it to log verbosely what it is doing.

The best approach for slf4j in a web application is to use the jdk14 bridge, allowing you to directly use the glassfish logging system.  As a web application is not allowed to directly use the underlying file system this is the only way you can be fully compliant and still log.

Comment: Is that the slf4j-jdk14 *bridge* or the *binding*. I see a binding listed but not a bridge.

Comment: The slf4j naming is rather confusing - I have to look it up every time.  It is the wrapped implementation "JDK14" I am thinking of which is slf4j-jdk14-x.y.z in the distribution archive.